# R: how to convert a data frame

Tags: r

I have a table like this:

```
    C1, C2, C3
1   1.1, 2.3, 5.5
2   3.3, 4.3, 2.5
```

I want to get it into the format of:

```
Type Time
 1   1.1
 1   2.3
 1   5.5
 2   3.3
 2   4.3
 2   2.5
```

I have tried:

```
 pivot_longer(cols = C1:C3, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Time")
```

However, I get the first set followed by the second.

Sample reproducible data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~ C1, ~ C2, ~ C3,
   1.1, 2.3, 5.5,
   3.3, 4.3, 2.5
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by the first set followed by the second? Do you want to just reorder the rows after you pivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code. For your solution to work you only need to add a row id before pivoting:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Type = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Type, names_to = "name", values_to = "Time") %>%
  select(-name)

# A tibble: 6 x 2
   Type  Time
  <int> <dbl>
1     1   1.1
2     1   2.3
3     1   5.5
4     2   3.3
5     2   4.3
6     2   2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
your.matrix <- rbind(
  c(1.1, 2.3, 5.5),
  c(3.3, 4.3, 2.5)
)
rownames(your.matrix) <- c("1","2")

your.matrix <- as.matrix( your.matrix ) # if you started with a data.frame

long.data <- data.frame(
    Type = rep( rownames(your.matrix), each=ncol(your.matrix) )
    Time = as.numeric(t(your.matrix))
)
```

Data being this simple, just turning it into a vector (with as.numeric), and handling the rownames-to-column operation by hand might be just as simple as pivoting.

To do it the chained dplyr way, rownames_to_column from tibble might come in handy:

```r
pivot_longer( 
    rownames_to_column( your.matrix, "Type" ), 
    cols=matches("^C\\d")
) %>% select(-name)
```

Output:

```
  Type  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 1       1.1
2 1       2.3
3 1       5.5
4 2       3.3
5 2       4.3
6 2       2.5
```